# Simplify Monadic Type Signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm still new to Haskell and am having trouble to find the correct type signature for a function.

I have this working, fairly straightforward function using `http-conduit` and `authenticate-oauth` which is side-effecting, so I don't care too much about the return value:

```
executeOAuthRequest oauth cred request =
    withManager $ \manager -> do
        signed <- signOAuth oauth cred request
        http signed manager
```

I would like to specify the correct type signature, but the output from GHCi looks rather terrifying to me:

```
executeOAuthRequest
  :: (monad-control-0.3.2.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
        IO m,
      Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.MonadThrow m,
      Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.MonadUnsafeIO m,
      Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m) =>
     OAuth
     -> Credential
     -> Request
     -> m (Response (ResumableSource (ResourceT m) ByteString))
```

The first three arguments (`OAuth`, `Credential`, `Request`) make sense to me, but I don't understand the long precondition for `m` and wonder if it's necessary to specify the full return value as GHCi suggests.

Rather than only providing the correct signature, I'd like to understand what the process behind finding and reducing the correct one looks like.

Comment: Note that `IO` implements all those constraints, so if you only need to use `IO`, you can just drop the constraint and specialize `m` to `IO` like this:  `OAuth -> Credential -> Request -> IO (Respond (ResumableSource (ResourceT IO) ByteString))`

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Thank you! Is this because IO is `* -> *` or is there another property because of which it satisfies all constraints?

Comment: @passy no. `* -> *` is a kind. It only means that `IO` is a type constructor (and `IO a` is a type for any type a). `IO` statisfies all constraints because the typeclasses instances are declared. as an example, `IO` has a `MonadIO` instance. The more complex type signature is useful because there are other monads which acts like `IO`, and which can be used instead.

Comment: @passy The idea is that those constraints make the type more flexible so that your function can be used with monads other than `IO`.  However, if you don't need that extra flexibility you can simplify the type by choosing a specific monad that implements those constraints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GHCi is giving you the most polymorphic signature, reading "any type `m` which is an instance of the classes `MonadThrow` from the `Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal` module, `MonadIO`, etc". The type-checker is sort of taking the union of all the constraints introduced by the types of those polymorphic functions you're composing in `executeOAuthRequest`.

Here's a simple example:

```
Prelude> let f n = n + 1
Prelude> :t f  -- GHC infers the polymorphic signature constrained to `Num`:
f :: Num a => a -> a
Prelude> let f :: Int -> Int ; f n = n + 1
Prelude> :t f
f :: Int -> Int
```

It might be that the only type which satisfies all those constraints in your function is `IO`, or there might be several. The usual way to check is by reading the haddocks, or doing e.g.

```
Prelude> :info IO
...
instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
Prelude> :info Monad
...
instance Monad [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

So if you only use your function in `IO` you can give it the type:

```
executeOAuthRequest
  :: OAuth
     -> Credential
     -> Request
     -> IO (Response (ResumableSource (ResourceT m) ByteString))
```

or you could keep the polymorphic signature, if for instance you're exporting this function in a library and think your users might want to use it in a different monad (maybe even by defining their own new type and making it an instance of `MonadIO`, `MonadThrow`, etc)

Comment: Terrific explanation, thank you. The note about the library is really interesting. I naively assumed that GHC's output is just noisy and reducing the signature would always be what you want, but haven't thought about the possibility that someone might want to use a different monad.